# Android Studio Giraffe : change mouse pointer color

Tags: android-studio

I updated from Android studio Flamingo to Giraffe recently, but now I have a grey edit mouse cursor when I move over my code.

The normal select is white, but the text edit stays grey in dark mode, so it's very hard to see on the screen.

How can I get a whiter text select when I'm in dark mode ?

[image: Default mouse cursor]